# Behavior of sequence in Merge Statement

Tags: database, merge, oracle11g, sequence

I have written an Oracle Merge statement Inside merge statement I'm using "sequence" using Function. Problem is that sequence not return next value. sequence return next to next value.

```
begin 
execute IMMEDIATE 'merge into dept t
using (select SEQ_DEPT_NEXTVAL_ON_DEMAND(''seq_dept'') deptno,  ''DEVELOPME'' DNAME, ''WASHINGTON'' LOC from dual ) S
on (t.deptno= s.deptno)
when not matched then 
insert(t.deptno,t.dname,t.loc)
values(s.deptno,s.dname,s.loc)';
--commit;
end;

create or replace FUNCTION seq_dept_nextval_on_demand (p_seq_name  IN  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_seq_val  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || p_seq_name || '.nextval from dual'
     INTO v_seq_val;
  RETURN v_seq_val;
END seq_dept_nextval_on_demand;


select seq_dept.currval from dual ;

Currval 
51 

But merge statement insert deptno as 53 instead of 52. It always skips one nextVal.
```

Comment: Why are you concerned?  Sequences are not guaranteed to provide gapless series of numbers.

Comment: I wanted to insert deptno like 51 52 53. And I have created sequence incremented by 1 that is my concern.

Comment: I think you're going about your requirement in the wrong way. Why are you joining on the deptno? That leaves you open to creating the same department name and location multiple times - perhaps your join should be on those. Then you can avoid the dynamic sql (which I don't see a need for the merge statement anyway) and remove the function.

Comment: actually I'm doing POC of sequence behavior in the Merge statement to generate Primary key value while merging data from source table.